# Unable to read website using Python requests or Urllib Module

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to read this particular webpage 
[NSE Option Chain](https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp)

But I don't ever get any response , No matter what. At the same time if I change link to google's website it works.
Could anyone from here help in solving the issue.

Here is my code

```
link="https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp"
import urllib
print ("Going to read")
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
print ("Read")
myfile = f.read()
print(myfile)
```

Comment: I think the server is dropping connections for non-browser sessions. Opens in chrome for me, but I can't hit the site with `requests` or `curl`

Comment: You may want to look into [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which allows you to run a browser session with python

Comment: What does it mean "don't get any response"? Your request fails with timeout or the server responses with some error code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it works for me both via browser and via Python [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library:

```
import requests

url = "https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

And `response.text` contains HTML page with table, so I can save it to a file and then open with my browser, and it looks similar (except for missing styles) to what I see on actual URL:

```
with open("page.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```